# How to get value from a looped table, trigger a function that stores that value in an array in vue

Tags: vue.js

I have an array in vue

```
 data() {
        return {
               myValues: [1,2,3,4],
               newValue:[]
                },
            }
    }
```

for every value in myValue plus 1, push value to newValue

now i've tried a couple of things which didn't work like using the @change=() reactivity but it's not  working.

here's what i've done

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Value</th
    <th>Value + 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="value in myValues" :key="value.id">
     <td>{{ value }}</td>
     <td><input type="text" @change="getValue(value+1)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <script>
   data() {
        return {
               myValues: [1,2,3,4],
               newValue:[]
                },
            }
    },
  methods: {
      getValue(id){
        this.newValue.push(id)
     }
    }
</script>
```

at the end of the day i want to have

```
newValue:[2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use computed property; Here's the code:

```js
data() {
  return {
    myValues: [1,2,3,4],
  };
},
computed: {
  newValues() {
    const newValues = []
    this.myValues.forEach(v => newValues.push(v + 1));
    return newValues;
  },
},
```